# Pushing something into a vector depending on its last element

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I would like to get the last element of a vector and use it to determine the next element to push in. Here's an example how it doesn't work, but it shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
let mut vector: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

if let Some(last_value) = vector.last() {
    vector.push(*last_value + 1);
}
```

I can't use `push` while the vector is also borrowed immutably:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `vector` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
4 |     if let Some(last_value) = vector.last() {
  |                               ------ immutable borrow occurs here
5 |         vector.push(*last_value + 1);
  |         ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
6 |     }
  |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## After Non-Lexical Lifetimes

Your original code [works as-is in Rust 2018](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=307ec646a197c8bae870f26cd9e7904c), which enables [non-lexical-lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423):

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    if let Some(last_value) = vector.last() {
        vector.push(*last_value + 1);
    }
}
```

The borrow checker has been improved to realize that the reference in `last_value` does not overlap with the mutable borrow of `vector` needed to push a new value in.

See [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423) for a similar case that the borrow checker is not yet smart enough to deal with (as of Rust 1.32).

## Before Non-Lexical Lifetimes

The result of `vector.last()` is an `Option<&i32>`. The reference in that value keeps the vector borrowed. We need to get rid of all references into the vector before we can push to it.

If your vector contains `Copy`able values, copy the value out of the vector to end the borrow sooner.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    if let Some(&last_value) = vector.last() {
        vector.push(last_value + 1);
    }
}
```

Here, I've used the pattern `Some(&last_value)` instead of `Some(last_value)`. This *destructures* the reference and forces a copy. If you try this pattern with a type that isn't `Copy`able, you'll get a compiler error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:4:17
  |
4 |     if let Some(&last_value) = vector.last() {
  |                 ^----------
  |                 ||
  |                 |hint: to prevent move, use `ref last_value` or `ref mut last_value`
  |                 cannot move out of borrowed content
```

If your vector does not contain `Copy`able types, you might want to clone the value first:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    if let Some(last_value) = vector.last().cloned() {
        vector.push(last_value + "abc");
    }
}
```

Or you can transform the value in another way such that the `.map()` call returns a value that doesn't borrow from the vector.

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    if let Some(last_value) = vector.last().map(|v| v.len().to_string()) {
        vector.push(last_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your first example in comparison with the OP's code? How exactly is it different and where does Copy come into play here?

Comment: @JimmyCuadra In the OP's code `last_value()` gets matched against `last_value`. Since `last_value()` returns a reference, `last_value` becomes a reference too. However, Francis changed the pattern to `&last_value`, so the reference matches the `&`, and the value itself matches `last_value` and therefore is copied by value. This is called destructuring.